# WCF Service fails to receive soap requests because of xml declaration

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, service

I have programmed an WCF Service which acts as an Event Receicer in C#. A Client sending following Soap Request to the Event Receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:sila="http://sila.coop" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ResponseEvent xmlns="http://sila.coop">
         <requestId>10</requestId>
         <returnValue>
            <returnCode>3</returnCode>
            <message>command 'Reset' completed successfully</message>
            <duration>PT0S</duration>
            <deviceClass>8</deviceClass>
         </returnValue>
         <responseData>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;ResponseData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sila.coop//schemata/ResponseType_1.2.xsd"&gt;&lt;/ResponseData&gt;</responseData>
      </ResponseEvent>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This one is rejected and in the Service Trace Viewer I can see that there was an exception throwed:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.Xml.XmlException, 
system.xml.xmlexception data at the root level is invalid. line 1 position 1
```

When I start the WCF Test client, I could send a request, which looks the following:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ResponseEvent
            xmlns="http://sila.coop"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <requestId>1</requestId>
            <returnValue>
                <returnCode>3</returnCode>
                <deviceClass>0</deviceClass>
            </returnValue>
        </ResponseEvent>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This one is working, it will go through the service.

Unfortunatley I'm not able to change the client. So how could I configure or change my Service, that it understands the topmost Request with the xml declaration?

I generated the code for the event receiver via the svcutil tool from an existing mock serivce in SoapUi:

Interface:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://sila.coop", ConfigurationName="EventReceiverSoap")]
public interface EventReceiverSoap
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://sila.coop/ResponseEvent", ReplyAction="*")]
    ResponseEventResponse ResponseEvent(ResponseEventRequest request);

}
```

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData= "EventReceiverSoap.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>


  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="EventReceiverSoap" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"    externalMetadataLocation="../wsdl/ls.wsdl" />/>
          <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Implementation:

```
//[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class EventReceiverSoapClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<EventReceiverSoap>, EventReceiverSoap
{

    public EventReceiverSoapClient()
    {
    }

    public EventReceiverSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public EventReceiverSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public EventReceiverSoapClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public EventReceiverSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public ResponseEventResponse ResponseEvent(ResponseEventRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.ResponseEvent(request);
    }


}
```

Comment: could u plz add your code to view how u receive your xml?

Comment: Hello, I don't have any special code for receiving the xml, I think it's all done with the System.serviceModel.

Comment: i think it better to write your own code to receive XML bcoz may be your xml contains hidden character so your  mock service not able to understand this

Comment: Ok, could you give an example how to do this, or give a link to an example?

Comment: does you have any implementation of your `EventReceiverSoap`? means add you class that inherit `EventReceiverSoap` interface

Comment: Why do you have responseData in the SOAP?  Remove this line!!!

Comment: I am not able to change the client code, unfortunately it is a closed source DLL library.